# How to make this sparse matrix and trie work in tandem

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, sparse-matrix, trie

I have a sparse matrix that has been exported to this format:

```
(1, 3) = 4
(0, 5) = 88
(6, 0) = 100
...
```

Strings are stored into a Trie data structure. The numbers in the previous exported sparse matrix correspond to the result of the lookup on the Trie.

Lets say the word "stackoverflow" is mapped to number '0'. I need to iterate the exported sparse matrix where the first element is equals to '0' and find the highest value.

For example:

```
(0, 1) = 4
(0, 3) = 8
(0, 9) = 100 <-- highest value
```

(0, 9) is going to win.

What would be the best implementation to store the exported sparse matrix? 
In general, what would be the best approach (data structure, algorithm) to handle this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absent memory or dynamism constraints, probably the best approach is to slurp the sparse matrix into a map from first number to the pairs ordered by value, e.g.,

```
matrix_map = {}  # empty map
for (first_number, second_number, value) in matrix_triples:
    if first_number not in matrix_map:
        matrix_map[first_number] = []  # empty list
    matrix_map[first_number].append((second_number, value))
for lst in matrix_map.values():
    lst.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)  # sort by value descending
```

Given a matrix like

```
(0, 1) = 4
(0, 3) = 8
(0, 5) = 88
(0, 9) = 100
(1, 3) = 4
(6, 0) = 100,
```

the finished product looks like this:

```
{0: [(9, 100), (5, 88), (3, 8), (1, 4)],
 1: [(3, 4)],
 6: [(0, 100)]}.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot of your answer. Forgive my ignorance but the snippet you provided is to find the highest value or store only the highest value? Because I need to store the whole exported sparse matrix. So my original question is what is the best data structure to store the sparse matrix and to lookup. Btw, by {} you mean [] ? I', not Python expert but I don't think Python uses {} :)  Thanks again for help and time.

Comment: @Chiron `{}` is a Python map. Instead of just the highest triple, you can store a list of triples, with the highest at the front (or even sorted by value descending).

Comment: Would you please give a text representation of what you mean? It will help me to visualize. Thanks.

Comment: @Chiron I added an example.

Comment: Would you please explain what do you mean by "Absent memory or dynamism constraints"? I really enjoyed learning from you :)

Comment: @Chiron This representation can be reasonably memory efficient, but it may not be appropriate if the sparse matrix doesn't fit in memory (the wildly disparate access times of memory and disk would dictate a different layout). If the matrix changes often, then a more complicated structure could allow us to update it faster.